# Adding Vlookup as hyperlink Tooltip Excel - Dynamic tooltips excel

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I was looking to create dynamic information on a cell when you don't have a lot of space but would like to display it.

I wanted to use on a job sheet to let the user know what the job No. referred to if their not familiar with it.

[image]

I used the hyperlink method combined with vba to achieve self updating list.

This is the hover over I wanted.

https://superuser.com/questions/1296838/customize-hyperlink-hover-over

But i wanted it dynamically updated from a table where I could update the table and it would pull the information and add the tooltips as descriptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is this

```
Sub toolmicro()
'
' toolmicro Macro

 Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Sheet1!C2:C30")
 Dim cel As Range
 For Each cel In rng.Cells
  With cel
  If cel.Value = "" Then
  
  Else
  Dim tooltiptoolmine As String

 tooltiptoolmine = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cel.Value, Sheet1.Range("A1:B3"), 2, False), "Add Description to job")



cel.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cel, Address:="", ScreenTip:=tooltiptoolmine



  End If
    
End With
Next cel



End Sub
```

The Range looks for a set of cells to add the if to you could make it a column like C:D.

It skips blanks
Has error handling if the description hasn't be written yet.

Applys the link based on vlookup.

Then to get it to automagically update as I add jobs to the list

This will look for a change on the worksheet and call the list update.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Call toolmicro


End Sub
```

If anyone has a better way let me know.